# Exclude directory from webpack

Tags: webpack

I have a subproject within my app that contains its own `node_modules/` and such. It's isolated from the main project in terms of scripts, but should to be within it. *This may not make sense, but it's true*.

The thing is, the node_modules (at least) are interfering with webpack. I'm getting errors like `Duplicate Identifier`, `Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable`, ...

By simply deleting the subproject directory the bundling starts to work.

---

Best solution scenario would be to add an exclude entry on the webpack config, but things don't work that way.

How can I fix this? I can't find a solution!

Comment: Webpack doesn't care about the subdirectory unless you import something from it. The issue is probably somewhere in your webpack config, maybe a misconfigured [`resolve`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the exclude prop in your loader.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-exclude

And you can control when to bundle or not the modules using a NODE_ENV and a script. I use this to development environment, instead of waiting for webpack to build all node_modules every time.

It's a simple inline if to check the NODE_ENV and build node modules or not using the exclude condition in the loader.

```
var FASTBUILD = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'fastbuild';
//This example is for loading all js
module: {
    rules: [
        FASTBUILD ? {test: /\.js?$/, loader: "your-loader-here", exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules")} : {test: /\.js?$/, loader: your-loader-here"}
    ]
}
```

And you can have this in your package.json so you just use `npm run dev`:

```
"scripts": {
//this if for build WITHOUT node_modules
    "dev": "set NODE_ENV=fastbuild&&webpack --watch"
  }
```

PS: This is configured for Windows and using Webpack 2.2